# I want to check whether frame exists or not on web page by using Selenium, how can do it

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, frame

After login to my application, sometimes a frame opens, which requires a click on the 'OK' button.
So, I have written the code below which switches to the frame, clicks on the OK button and again switches to default.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("InlineDialog_Iframe")));
driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("pending_email_close_btn_id"))).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

But, if frame doesn't appear then code gives error saying that the frame doesn't exist.

Please let me know how can I check whether the frame exists or not by using 'if' loop or by any other method?

Thanks.

Comment: whether it exists, or whether it is visible?

Comment: sorry i mean 'visible'.

Answer (score 0):

hi there i had to do some stuff in the past regards to iframes as well and it was very confusing for me as well,

so the very first within you need to understand is that the iframe is actually a web page "inside other web-page" due so you will need to `switchTo().frame(...stuff..)` to be able to do something

than when you finish you need to get the initial frame `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` so you king of move from one page to the other

regards to find the element which you are after in the iframe i suggest you find any element which will always be present and wrap it with a try

i also suggest you to create a class which will hold your code and wait for JS, Angular, Jquery ...

example from my code:

```
try {
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id^='xdm_default']")));//change focus to iframe
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"))));//wait for html in the iframe
    WebElement divCardsGrid = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class^='CardsGrid']"))));

    if (!divCardsGrid.findElements(By.tagName("a")).isEmpty()) {//check for external links

} catch (WebDriverException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
}


//change the focus to the initial frame
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));<br/>
if(iframes.size() > 0)<br/>
{<br/>
        // Frames is Present <br/>
        driver.switchTo().frame("a077aa5e"); //switching the frame by ID<br/>
        driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("pending_email_close_btn_id"))).click();<br/>
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();<br/>
}else{<br/>
        // No Frames <br/>
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/a/img")).sendKeys(“----------”);<br/>
}<br/>
```

Comment: Also, don't only post code. Please elaborate your answer